# Howto Include Extension Template in Customer Account

Tags: extensions, magento2.2.2, custom-template

We are trying to integrate the output of an extension into a customized phtml template:

The extension is called Magetrend Newsletter Popup Pro which normally creates a pop that is being triggered by js. It offers the opportunity to add custom fields for special target groups. We are using this feature aswell as the pop-up feature.

We would like to integrate the same output as in the above mentioned pop-up into the customer account to facilitate customers to change their settings.

The template to be used for this would be

```
./vendor/magento/module-customer/view/frontend/templates/form/newsletter.phtml
```

which we already placed in

```
./app/design/frontend/Vendor/theme/Magento_Customer/templates/form/newsletter.phtml
```

How would we be able to integrate the following template there:

```
./app/design/frontend/Vendor/theme/Magetrend_NewsletterPopup/templates/newsletterpopup/popup.phtml
```

We don't find anything on this in the web.

Comment: Could you please share with me exact path where located "popup.phtml" in  Magetrend Newsletter Popup Pro.

Comment: the popup.phtml is located at 
`./app/code/Magetrend/NewsletterPopup/view/frontend/templates/newsletterpopup/popup.phtml`
We also already asked the Magetrend support, but they couldn't help with this issue.

Comment: have run set:up command after override popup.phtml file ?

Comment: yes, several times, but we haven't integrated the popup.phtml into the newsletter.phtml because we have no idea how to do it.

Comment: Wait, do you want modified "newsletter.phtml" or "popup.phtml" ?

Comment: I want to have the output of popup.phtml in newsletter.phtml (which is the default newsletter config within the customer account area, but is missing the custom fields we added with newsletter popup pro)